# Algorithm help - function to deal with school "letter days". A 6 day repeating week

Tags: php, algorithm, series

I've spent much too much time on this and can't get it. I am looking for a function that returns a "letter day" given a date.

Letter days are a 6 day week with the days A through F excluding weekends. If Monday is A then Friday is E and the following Monday is F with Tuesday A. Get it?

```
Week 1: a, b, c, d, e, null, null
Week 2: f, a, b, c, d, null, null
Week 3: e, f, a, b, c, null, null
```

Pick an arbitrary date to start as a reference. For the sake of the function let's agree that Monday 22 April is a C day.

Thanks!

Comment: If I interpret your question correctly, you need to look at modular arithmetic. Specifically, you need to start by calculating the number of days the date is from the starting date, and then look at that number mod 6 (or 5?). Then match the result to the corresponding letter.

Comment: @doliver I think it dosen't work with modulo, cause you need to ignore weekends.

Comment: You need to make some adjustments. Let me see if I can write some code real quick.

Comment: Yeah, what doliver said.  Understanding the underlying mathematics is going to point you in precisely the right direction.  This slideshow covers decimal (base-10) to octal (base-8) conversions, which is pretty much where you want to go, except in your case, you're turning base-5 into base-6.  http://www.wisc-online.com/Objects/ViewObject.aspx?ID=TMH5306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
<?PHP
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-04-22');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-04-30');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$numDays = $interval->format('%d');

$calibration = 2; //April 22, 2013 is a "C" day.
$numWeekDays = $numDays - 2 * floor($numDays / 7);
$answer = ($numWeekDays + $calibration) % 6 + 1; 

echo chr(64 + $answer);
?>
```

Comment: It returns '@' for 2013-04-25, which should be an "F". :(

Comment: @ToddB I think I fixed it; please let me know if you find another discrepancy.

Comment: @ToddB hope it serves you well. I removed the extra 6 in the parenthetical in the penultimate line. (for some reason I thought numbers-lower-than-6 modulo 6 were returning zero)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the idea:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    if ($i % 7 == 0)
        echo "<BR>";
    echo GetLetter ($i) . ",";
}

function GetLetter ($numDays)
{
    $letters = Array ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F");
    $nullRet = false;
    $currentLetter = 0;
    $lastLetter = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $numDays; $i++)
    {
        if (($i+2) % 7 == 0 || ($i+1) % 7 == 0)
        {
            $nullRet = true;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            $nullRet = false;
            $lastLetter = $currentLetter;
            $currentLetter++;
        }
    }
    if ($nullRet)
    {
        return "null";
    }
    else
    {
        return $letters[$lastLetter%6];
    }
}
?>
```

Can you work out the dates on your own from this? It's pretty easy from here. The idea is that you want to loop through the days of the week and skip sat and sun. You increment on all other days and check what they are mod 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo get_letter('29-4-2013');
echo get_letter('30-4-2013');
echo get_letter('1-5-2013');
echo get_letter('2-5-2013');
echo get_letter('3-5-2013');
echo PHP_EOL.'------------------'.PHP_EOL;
echo get_letter('6-5-2013');
echo get_letter('7-5-2013');
echo get_letter('8-5-2013');
echo get_letter('9-5-2013');
echo get_letter('10-5-2013');

function get_letter($set_date){
$map=array('a','b','c','d','e','f');

$start_letter = 'c';
$start_date = strtotime("22-4-2013");

$target_date = strtotime($set_date);

$start_date_w = date('w',$start_date);

$target_date_w = date('w',$target_date);

if($target_date_w == 6 || $target_date_w == 0){
return 'null';
}

$bwt_d = ($target_date-$start_date) / 86400;

$week_count =  floor($start_date_w + $bwt_d /7)-1;


$bwt_d5 = $bwt_d -$week_count*2;

$aa=($bwt_d5+1)%6;


return $map[$aa];
}
```

try it
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/295d52d2ef2ecdbd7c2d2b93c747254e864fdf9c